# How to handle BIGINT on PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a project that create a web page using PHP Laravel, and want to create a user login. On the database I created UserID column, with varchar as the data type, the User ID format 'USxxxxxxxxxx' the x are number and it will auto increment. So I create a function to substring the number and change it to Int so it will auto increment when new user register to the web. After the increment, the number will store back to a string.

My question is is PHP Laravel can handle 10 digits number(Billion) and what data type that should I use on PHP Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use VARCHAR for BIGINT. Use `bigIncrements()` in Laravel migrations for increment:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

And `bigInteger()` for BIGINT:

```
$table->bigInteger('votes');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#columns

Comment: but he say UserID first 2 character is US so how he use BIGINT?

Comment: @ImBS add US part in the app maybe? With an accessor or manually.

Answer (score 0):

> Core PHP Logic you should be implement as Laravel syntax

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER by `UserID` DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($qry);

$last_id = $row['UserID'];
$userid = substr($string, 2);
$userid = $userid + 1;
$userid = 'US'.$userid;

// Now you can Insert

$insert_qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user` (`UserID`) VALUES ('".$userid."')");
```

Comment: what the LIMIT 1 effect?

Comment: LIMIT 1 and order by DESC so you get only 1 Last record